# Need to INDEX/MATCH or VLOOKUP non-matched values

Tags: excel, indexing, match, vlookup

**How do I return 6/7/2017 at the #N/A in AE39 for "Completion Instance = 10" (second image)?**

If you look at the "Cume Rounded" column in the first image, you'll see that I complete the 9th instance on 6/7 and the 11th instance on 6/8, but how do I show that the 10th instance *also* completes on 6/7?

[Calculate Completions via Continuous Production Rates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/afxP0.png)

**Currently this formula in AE30:AE47 gets me most of the way:**
=INDEX($A$30:$A$1552,MATCH(AD30,$Z$30:$Z$1552,0))

[Completion Dates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nyNGL.png)

I'm guessing I need to replace one of the MATCH operators with something else and probably use an array formula but I can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: How would you be able to show that? Would the result be '10-11' or?

Comment: or would the 6/7 line be duplicated

Comment: The 6/7 should be duplicated and show up in AE10. I'd like functionality that is similar to how vlookup can do approximate returns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How do I return 6/7/2017 at the #N/A in AE39 for "Completion Instance = 10" (second image)?

Select ColumnAE, HOME > Editing, Find & Select, Go To Special..., select Formulas (only) and check Errors (only), <kbd>OK</kbd>, <kbd>=</kbd>,  <kbd>↑</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Comment: I'm getting an error with the current formula because there is no "10" in the "Cume Rounded" column.  

"10" is between 9 and 11, so I want to return the value in the row that corresponds with the lesser of the two. Ideally the formula would duplicate the 9 value, which is 6/7.

Comment: Ah I see, so yes, this definitely does work for this instance. I was looking for a formula that would do this for me every time, as I plan on running different scenarios. Thank you for the tip and this will help me until I can figure out a way to not have to a set cell-reference.